# Searching for words in a dictionary

Tags: performance, regex, hash-map, perl

I'm using an open source program called MElt which lemmatize (give the lemma example:giving-->give) of words. MElt works on Linux and it's programmed in Perl and Python. So far it's working good but it take way too much time to give the results. I looked into the code and located the loop responsible for this:

```
while (<LEFFF>) { 
  chomp;
  s/ /_/g;
#  s/(\S)-(\S)/\1_-_\2/g;
  /^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)(\t|$)/ || next;
  $form = $1; $cats = $2; $lemma = $3;
  #print "$form \n";
  #print "$cats \n";
  #print "$lemma \n";
  if ($lower_case_lemmas) {
    $lemma = lc($lemma);
  }
  if ($it_mapping) {
    next if ($form =~ /^.+'$/);
    next if ($form eq "dato" && $lemma eq "datare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "stato" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "stata" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "parti" && $lemma eq "parto"); # bourrin
    if ($cats =~ /^(parentf|parento|poncts|ponctw)$/) {$cats = "PUNCT"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(PRO)$/) {$cats = "PRON"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(ARTPRE)$/) {$cats = "PREDET"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(VER|ASP|AUX|CAU)$/) {$cats = "VERB"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(CON)$/) {$cats = "CONJ"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(PRE)$/) {$cats = "PREP"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(DET)$/) {$cats = "ADJ"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(WH)$/) {$cats = "PRON|CONJ"}
    next if ($form =~ /^(una|la|le|gli|agli|ai|al|alla|alle|col|dagli|dai|dal|dalla|dalle|degli|dei|del|della|delle|dello|nei|nel|nella|nelle|nello|sul|sulla)$/ && $cats eq "ART");
    next if ($form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ && $cats eq "ADJ");
    next if ($form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ && $cats eq "PRON");
    next if ($form =~ /^quell[aei]$/ && $cats eq "ADJ");
    next if ($form =~ /^quell[aei]$/ && $cats eq "PRON");
    next if ($form =~ /^ad$/ && $cats eq "PREP");
    next if ($form =~ /^[oe]d$/ && $cats eq "CONJ");
  }
  $qmlemma = quotemeta ($lemma);
  for $cat (split /\|/, $cats) {
    if (defined ($cat_form2lemma{$cat}) && defined ($cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form}) && $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} !~ /(^|\|)$qmlemma(\||$)/) {
      $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} .= "|$lemma";
    } else {
      $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} = "$lemma";
      $form_lemma_suffs = "@".$form."###@".$lemma;
      while ($form_lemma_suffs =~ s/^(.)(.+)###\1(.+)/\2###\3/) {
        if (length($2) <= 8) {
          $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{$3}++;
          if ($multiple_lemmas) {
            $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{__ALL__}++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The variable `LEFFF` is a dictionary composed of 490489 lines.  So, the loop is comparing the words with all the dictionary lines one by one.  This is too much. Any ideas how to optimize this?

Here's a preview of how `LEFFF` is structured:

```
touant  VPR touer   0
intimiste   NC  intimiste   1
intimiste   ADJ intimiste   0
phonologiques   ADJ phonologique    1
condescendirent V   condescendre    1
enchaussez  VIMP    enchausser  1
enchaussez  V   enchausser  0
riotiez VS  rioter  1
riotiez V   rioter  0
Eyzin-Pinet NPP Eyzin-Pinet 1
dentaires   NC  dentaire    0
dentaires   ADJ dentaire    1
classe  VIMP    classer 0
classe  VS  classer 1
```

Comment: WRT the update: The code you have given us is a very small snippet from the actual code. The two answers just tell how a constant factor can be reduced. This doesn't matter much, because optimizing the algorithmic complexity would be more important. Unfortunately, this would require changes to the data structure you are using, which would require changes throughout the source. WRT the hash table idea: Perl has this as a builtin data type. Indexing the file itself isn't a good idea: we would need to index line offsets to `seek` them. Ugh. You were thinking “database”, which would be better.

Comment: Thank you Amon, I'm implementing the other idea now, I'll probably post another subject somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is difficult, especially without being a linguist. However, the code is horrid, and I can fix that.

---

`s/ /_/g` should be `tr/ /_/`, as single-character transliterations are more efficient than full-fledged regex matches.

---

```
/^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)(\t|$)/ || next;
$form = $1; $cats = $2; $lemma = $3;
```

should be

```
my ($form, $cats, $lemma) = split /\t/, $_, 4 or next;
```

The `.*?` in the regex is a big no-no. It wants to split the line into three parts at tabs – so let's use `split`.

---

Certain stuff could be written more readable:

```
  if ($it_mapping) {
    next if $form =~ /.'$/  # optimized from /^.+'$/
         or $form eq "dato"  && $lemma eq "datare"
         or $form eq "stato" && $lemma eq "stare"
         or $form eq "stata" && $lemma eq "stare"
         or $form eq "parti" && $lemma eq "parto"
         or $cats eq "ART" && $form =~ /^(?:una|la|le|gli|agli|ai|al|alla|alle|col|dagli|dai|dal|dalla|dalle|degli|dei|del|della|delle|dello|nei|nel|nella|nelle|nello|sul|sulla)$/;

    # removing capture groups, using eq where appropriate, using postfix if:
    $cats = "PUNCT"     if $cats =~ /^(?:parentf|parento|poncts|ponctw)$/;
    $cats = "PRON"      if $cats eq 'PRO';
    $cats = "PREDET"    if $cats eq 'ARTPRE';
    $cats = "VERB"      if $cats =~ /^(?:VER|ASP|AUX|CAU)$/;
    $cats = "CONJ"      if $cats eq 'CON';
    $cats = "PREP"      if $cats eq 'PRE';
    $cats = "ADJ"       if $cats eq 'DET';
    $cats = "PRON|CONJ" if $cats eq 'WH';

    # cheaper test (equality) as early as possible
    next if $cats eq "PREP" && $form eq 'ad'
         or $cats eq "ADJ"  && $form =~ /^quest[aei]$/
         or $cats eq "PRON" && $form =~ /^quest[aei]$/
         or $cats eq "ADJ"  && $form =~ /^quell[aei]$/
         or $cats eq "PRON" && $form =~ /^quell[aei]$/
         or $cats eq "CONJ" && $form =~ /^[oe]d$/;
  }
```

Note that I did not optimize the gargantuan regex – the *trie optimization* will transform that into a state machine, which is far more efficient. This regex match was also moved before the `$cats` normalization in order to bail out as early as possible.

---

```
$qmlemma = quotemeta ($lemma);
```

should be

```
my $qmlemma = quotemeta ($lemma);
```

because lexical variables can be more efficient, and it makes it easier to reason about the code.

---

The next part (looping through the `$cat`s) is very hackish, and could be done more efficient with a different data structure.

(I removed my `no autovivification` recommendation because that behaviour is needed in the `else` clause again, and it does not effectively save much).

The regex should be changed to `/(?:^|[|])$qmlemma(?:[|]|$)/` to avoid unneccessary capturing (and to make it more readable).

---

The else-branch should be changed to

```
$cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} = $lemma; # avoid unneccessary stringification
my $form_lemma_suffs = '@' . $form . '###@' . $lemma;  # lexical variables!!!
while ($form_lemma_suffs =~ s/^(.)(.+)###\1(.+)/\2###\3/) {
  if (length($2) <= 8) {
    $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{$3}++;
    $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{__ALL__}++ if $multple_lemmas;
  }
}
```

Most of the changes are meant to improve readability (postfix `if`, spacing). If I grok that code correctly, then it might be able to change this to

```
$cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} = $lemma; # avoid unneccessary stringification

my ($form_suff, $lemma_suff) = ($form, $lemma);
while (length($form_suff) and substr($form_suff, 0, 1, '') eq substr($lemma_suff, 0, 1, '')) {
  if (length($form_suff) <= 8) {
    $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$form_suff}{$lemma_suff}++;
    $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$form_suff}{__ALL__}++ if $multiple_lemmas;
  }
}
```

C-style string manipulation with `substr` is far more efficient than regexes with captures and backrefs.

Comment: Thank you very much Jamal,
I'll try to implement all of this (it's probably gonna take a while as I'm more used to C# programming) and I'll keep you posted

Comment: @Med: Amon, you mean?  I didn't answer this question (only made some edits). :-)

Comment: Oh...My bad yeah yeah I meant Amon ...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get rid of the regular-expressions, because they are quite heavy to compute.

But if you need them, have a look at the answer in this post: [precompile regexps once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit)

Comment: The `/o` modifier is practically obsolete, because perl is quite good at compiling constant regexes only once. I am more concerned with the style of the regexes – lots of unneccessary captures, and sometimes string equality would be the better test.

Comment: I meant 'using a regex object' not to use /o. But avoid the regeps would be better.